# Failure comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I have a function that is:

```
int accept_connection(void);
```

I am trying to make an error statement if it returns negative and I am getting a warning for comparison between pointer and integer.

Here is what I have written:

```
pthread_t dis;
if(accept_connection == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to accept connection\n");
    pthread_exit(&dis);
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
  if(accept_connection == -1)
```

is an attempt to check the *function pointer*, not the function return value. That is why compiler is screaming at you.

You need to make the function call instead and use the return value (`int`). Use

```
if( accept_connection() == -1 )
```